# Clojure lib for DB migration with custom clojure code execution support

Tags: clojure, database-migration

I am using [migratus](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus) for DB migration in project. It works quite well. But now I decide to store serialized data in database. I see no possibilities to change serialized data by SQL (i.e. by **migratus**).

So the question is, is there any clojure lib for database migration, which supports both SQL and some sort code execution?